# Live camera feed is not working on ip address of wifi router on django server

Tags: python, android, html, django

I have a Django server setup and I want to access the website from an Android device for testing. The webpage consists of a live camera feed. Here's the HTML code for the camera feed.

```html
<canvas id="camera--sensor"></canvas>        
<video id="camera--view" autoplay playsinline></video>        
<img src="//:0" alt="" id="camera--output">        
<button id="camera--trigger">Take a picture</button>
```

Now when I run `python manage.py runserver` command, the camera feed is visible in the *localhost*. But on running `python manage.py runserver wifi_ip:port_no`, the camera feed is not working.
Is there anything I can do to make it work? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you should get `IP address can't be assigned to` Error how you run project on your wifi_ip address?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to run your Django project on `wifi_port`, you'd just run it on `0.0.0.0` IP, and with any free port you want like `8008` and in your android phone you can see the camera feed if you connect to that wifi router via entering the IP of your system which you can get it with below command in Unix based systems:

```bash
➜ ip a
```

The output should contain something like this with other numbers or letters:

```
...
en0: flags=8543<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether e8:4e:89:50:e3:14
    inet 192.168.1.103/24 brd 192.168.1.255 en0
...
```

And you should enter for example `192.168.1.103:selected_port` on your Android device to see the camera feed.